# JMeter variables from one post http request to another

Tags: java, json, jmeter

I've got a JMeter issue... The problem is: i'm sending a http request by POST method to a website and then the page returns me 100 responses, for example one of the answers:
Answer:

```
{
            "Category": "XX",
            "NumberX": 5100051,
            "Class": "CLASS_1",
            "NumberY": 5100136,
            "arrivalDate": "2022-06-22T04:36:00",
            "departureDate": "2022-06-21T23:58:00"
},
```

and then i have to save some of the values with a JSON extractor to variables.

Then I have second one http request by POST method, where in the body i have to use these variables. And my problem is that i don't how to count these variables in the body... With one data it's working, for more i don't know how to iterate it... Body in the second request:

```
 {
               "vehicleCategory": "${Category}",
               "NumberOfTasks": "${NumberX}",
               "departureDate": "${departureDate}",
               "arrivalDate": "${arrivalDate_}"
 }
```

I want to see query responses to each of the previous 100 values...
I hope i I clearly described the problem... Is there anybody who can help me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you give "Match No" as `-1` in the JSON Extractor:

[image]

it will generate the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
Category_1=first match
Category_2=second match
....

Category_matchNr=100 (or whatever is the number of matches)
```

So you will be able to iterate these values by:

1. Adding a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with "Loop Count" set to `${Category_matchNr}`

   [image]
2. In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) body reference the variables as:

   ```
   {
     "vehicleCategory": "${__V(Category_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}",
     "NumberOfTasks": "${__V(NumberX_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}",
     "departureDate": "${__V(departureDate_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}",
     "arrivalDate": "${__V(arrivalDate__${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}"
   }
   ```

   [image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)